# IgnoreSerializableAttribute not found in DefaultContractResolver when switching from .NET v4.7.2 to .NET Standard v2.0

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.7.2

I'm in the process of migrating one of our libraries from .NET v4.7.2 to .NET Standard v2.0.

This code compiles when using .NET v4.7.2

```
var resolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true,
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(true, true),
};
```

but when using .NET Standard it does not. Apparently IgnoreSerializableAttribute is not part of DefaultContractResolver in v9.01 of Newtonsoft.Json when using .NET Standard.

I'm using v9.01 of Newtonsoft.Json as we're still using v1.0 Azure functions and they only work with v9.01.

Can anyone explain what's happening and why there's a difference between Newtonsoft.Json v9.01 in .NET v4.7.2 and .NET Standard v2.0?

Comment: Newtonsoft JSON v9.01 only targets .NET Standard 1.0

Comment: Just checked my project settings and Target Framework is .NET Standard 2.0, I assume that means a .NET Standard 2.0 project can consume .NET Standard 1.0?

Comment: Yes, but Microsoft's [`System.SerializableAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=net-6.0#applies-to) did not exist in .NET Standard 1.0.  If I recall, MSFT introduced it into .NET Standard 2.0 as part of the partial back-port of binary serialization (now deprecated).  When Json.NET added support for .NET Standard 2.0 in [release 11](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1) support for `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` got included.

Comment: Incidentally, as shown in the [reference source for `DefaultContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L179), `IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true` is set by default, so you could just not bother setting it explicitly.

Comment: Do these comments answer your question?

Comment: Yes, very comprehensive. Do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You do not need to set [`IgnoreSerializableAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm) to `true` because it is `true` by default.**  This can be seen in the [reference source for `DefaultContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L179):

> ```cs
>        public DefaultContractResolver()
>        {
> #if HAVE_BINARY_SERIALIZATION
>            IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
> #endif
>
> #pragma warning disable 618
>            DefaultMembersSearchFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
> #pragma warning restore 618
>
>            _contractCache = new ThreadSafeStore<Type, JsonContract>(CreateContract);
>        }
> ```

Thus on all versions of Json.NET, the following code will create a contract resolver that ignores the `[Serializable]` attribute:

```cs
var resolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(true, true),
};
```

**To answer your specific question as to why `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` is not present in Json.NET v9.0.1 when targeting .NET Standard 2.0**, it is because [v9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1) actually only targets .NET Standard 1.0, and Microsoft's [`System.SerializableAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=net-6.0#applies-to) did not exist in .NET Standard 1.0. If I recall, MSFT introduced it into .NET Standard 2.0 as part of the partial port of binary serialization (now [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)).   When Json.NET added support for .NET Standard 2.0 in [release 11](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1), support for `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` got included.